# what is the best way to update LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice

How to update to LibreOffice version 4 to version 5

Comment: How did you do your initial installation?  Did you use **apt-get** or was it installed from the **.deb** file on the libreoffice.org website?

Answer (score 0):

The version we have is 4.4. If you want to install 5+ you will need to download the installer from the Libreoffice site.

The english version for x64 can be found [here](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/?type=deb-x86&version=5.0&lang=en-US). You can use Ubuntu software center to install it.